# Magento 2 Add Datetime picker in system.xml

Tags: magento2, datepicker

I want to add date picker with time in configuration section in my custom module.

I followed Webkul link

[webkul link](http://webkul.com/blog/add-date-picker-magento2-configuration-section-using-system-xml/)

But from this I can only able to see date picker time picker is not appearing.
How I will add time picker?

Comment: You want just date with current time?

Comment: No admin can set different time from picker.

Comment: **The correct answer you can find here :** https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202487/date-field-system-xml/202493#202493

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `datetimepicker` like this:

```
$html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
        require(["jquery", "jquery/ui"], function (jq) {
            jq(document).ready(function () {
                jq("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '").datetimepicker( { dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" } );
                jq(".ui-datepicker-trigger").removeAttr("style");
                jq(".ui-datepicker-trigger").click(function(){
                    jq("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '").focus();
                });
            });
        });
        </script>';
// return datetime picker element
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Comment: in my case it's not working i am use same code from webkul and replace script from above script still i can't get time in datepicker.

Comment: @SanjayGohil try to clean a cache

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gbmw68      check this screen shot i am doing anything wrong ?

Comment: @SanjayGohil Seems that all is ok. Could you share a complete module somewhere on github or bitbucket?

Comment: Hi @SiarheyUchukhlebau  its working perfectly i need to know about if i want to set am and pm format what need to be done thanks ?

Comment: @Vinodkumar [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848383/how-to-set-am-pm-format-in-jquery-using-datetimepicker) you can find an answer. Just add `ampm: true` option and it should work.

Comment: @Vinodkumar It should looks like this: `.datetimepicker( { dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", ampm: true } )`

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau still It is showing in 24hrs format, I am using following code:      $("#endtime").datetimepicker( { dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", ampm: true} );
               $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").removeAttr("style");
               $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").click(function(){
                   $("#endtime").focus();
               });

Comment: @Vinodkumar I will try to reproduce it and then write to you.

Comment: adding `mage/calendar` to the DI array of requirejs make it working in magento 2.2