# Date field system.xml

Tags: magento2, date

I wonder what 'date' type needs in `system.xml`. I keep getting the error :

**system.xml (only the field):**

```
<field id="date" translate="label" type="date" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
<label>Start sync from :</label>
</field>
```

**error :**

> Exception #0 (Exception): Output format is not specified. Please
>   specify "format" key in constructor, or set it using setFormat().

**If i add a format :**

```
        <field id="date" translate="label" type="date" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
            <label>Start sync from :</label>
            <format>yyyy-MM-dd</format>
        </field>
```

**error :**

> Element 'format': This element is not expected.

**So what wants it? And how can i add time to it? (i need a epoch time eventually in the DB).**

**EDIT :**

This error comes from :

`\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Date` : 150-158

```
$dateFormat = $this->getDateFormat() ?: $this->getFormat();
        $timeFormat = $this->getTimeFormat();
        if (empty($dateFormat)) {
            throw new \Exception(
                'Output format is not specified. ' .
                'Please specify "format" key in constructor, or set it using setFormat().'
            );
        }
```

Comment: I found the solution for me at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174840/magento-2-create-date-with-time-attribute-for-product

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a simple way to achieve that:

**app/code/Vendor/Checkout/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="mycustom" translate="label" sortOrder="450">
            <label>My Custom Setting</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="mycustom" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>My Custom Setting</label>
            <tab>mycustom</tab>
            <resource>Magento_Checkout::config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="mydate" translate="label" type="date" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>My Date Field</label>
                    <frontend_model>Vendor\Checkout\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Date</frontend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Checkout/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Date.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Checkout\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

class Date extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->setDateFormat(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
        $element->setTimeFormat(null);
        return parent::render($element);
    }
}
```

Image:

[image]

Tested on Magento 2.2.0

**Edit by Swat :**

If you want to add a time picker :

```
public function render(AbstractElement $element)
{
    $element->setDateFormat(DateTime::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
    $element->setTimeFormat('HH:mm:ss');
    $element->setShowsTime(true);
    return parent::render($element);
}
```

[image]

Comment: if you can add this to your answer :        $element->setDateFormat(DateTime::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
        $element->setTimeFormat('HH:mm:ss');
        $element->setShowsTime(true); then i will accept it as an answer

Comment: @SwAt.Be you can edit my answer.

Comment: @John i didnt test that out but i guess if you do so that it will return nothing. Maybe it has an unset function instead of a setdate function? unsetDateFormat()/ Or a setShowsDate(false)

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, how can we use time picker only? without date calendar

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269454/how-to-implement-time-picker-in-magento-2-admin-system-xml